# Efficiently create numpy array with decreasing values moving away from center

Tags: python, numpy

Let `N` be an odd positive integer. I want to create a square 2D grid of shape `N x N` where the center element is `N`, the surrounding 8-neighborhood has value `N-1`, the elements around that neighborhood have value `N-2` etc., so that finally the "outer shell" of the array has value `N//2`. I can accomplish this using `np.pad` in a for loop that iteratively adds "shells" to the array:

```
def pad_decreasing(N):
    assert N % 2 == 1
    a = np.array([[N]])
    for n in range(N-1, N//2, -1):
        a = np.pad(a, 1, mode='constant', constant_values=n)
    return a
```

Example output:

```
In: pad_decreasing(5)
Out: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

**Question.** Can I accomplish this in a "vectorized" form that doesn't resort to for loops. This code is fairly slow for `N` large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance between the center and any point in the grid can be written as `np.maximum(np.abs(row - center), np.abs(col - center))`; Then *N* minus this distance gives the *onion* you need:

```
N = 5

# the x and y coordinate of the center point
center = (N - 1) / 2

# the coordinates of the square array
row, col = np.ogrid[:N, :N]

# N - distance gives the result
N - np.maximum(np.abs(row - center), np.abs(col - center))

# array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
#        [3, 4, 5, 4, 3],
#        [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```